# Use vim's Tabularize plugin to only match the first occurance of a delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, vim, format

Having been unable to find a linux based SQL beautifier to pipe my mySQL snippets to, I will settle for simply tabularizing my mySQL code. I want to turn this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUP
(
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   GROUPNAME VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE,
   ACTIVE BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,

   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
```

into this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUP
(
   ID         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   GROUPNAME  VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE,
   ACTIVE     BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,

   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
```

But if I do `:Tabularize /\` I get

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUP
(
        ID          INT           NOT        NULL         AUTO_INCREMENT,
        USERID      INT           NOT        NULL,
        GROUPNAME   VARCHAR(15)   UNIQUE,
        ACTIVE      BOOLEAN       DEFAULT    TRUE,

        PRIMARY     KEY(ID),
        FOREIGN     KEY           (USERID)   REFERENCES   USER(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB
```

How do I only align on the first space after the identifier (or alternatively, where do I find a command line SQL beautifier = ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid Tabularize repeating your pattern  to match other fields, you have to
anchor it.  At the beginning  makes more  sense in this  case, so you  can try
something like this:

```
:Tab /^\s*\w*
```

There is only  one field with this pattern  in your line. But be  careful — it
might not happen in your example, but  this matches the big majority of lines,
thus it  might be  a good  idea to apply  Tabularize only  in a  range (either
explicitly or by selecting the lines in visual mode).

Comment: Thanks. Although not in my question, I put this remapping in my .vimrc file to quickly align columns with 2 pad sapces by visually selecting lines and typing `<leader>mal` (`M`ysql `AL`ign) `vnoremap <leader>mal :Tabularize /^\s*\w*/l2<CR>`

Comment: That's it, @puk. And sorry, I apparently missed the 2 spaces padding. Also, if you will always do this on indented lines you can use `/^\s\+\w\+` which will reduce the number of incorrect guessed lines. Then you can apply it without visually selecting first, and save some keystrokes :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it won't work for mySQL create tables b/c I want to align the columns for, well, columns (ie. `ID`, `GROUPNAME`, `ACTIVE`), but not for other keywords like `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`

Answer (score 0):

To provide more depth to the answers already given, another approach is to include the rest of the line to the matching delimiter:

```
:Tab /\d.*
```

This will align everything beginning with the first digit, no matter how many more digits follow and no matter what came before.
Depending on the situation, this may be a better choice, than specifying an anchor.

Comment: Note that this is only additional info, considering the general title "how to only match the first occurrence of a delimiter". It does *not* match the example provided.
However, it's silly to post another question with the same title, but a different example.

Comment: Depending on your exact usecase, you may also want to take a look at:
https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular/blob/master/doc/Tabular.txt#L133